# Which Package need for Chunk and Color Class

Tags: itext, itext7

I am using Itext7 to generate pdf from html string using C#
There are not colors under Color class.

```
.SetFontColor(Color.RED)// there is not RED property
```

I already have `using iText.Kernel.Colors;`
Which package I need to install for this?

same for `Chunk linebreak = new Chunk` which package I need to install

and how I can add links in paragraph using `new Paragraph(` to add in pdf doc??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iText 7 is **a complete rewrite** of the previous iText versions, hence many things are different.

For instance:

- The color constants are no longer stored in the `Color` class, but in the `ColorConstants` class. Instead of `Color.RED`, you now need `ColorConstants.RED`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/colors/ColorConstants.html#RED
- The `Chunk` class no longer exists. The class that comes closest to `Chunk` is `Text`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Text.html
- The `Anchor` class that was used to add links to a `Paragraph` is now called `Link`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Link.html

The `ColorConstants` class is in the kernel package; `Text` and `Link` are in the layout package. This addresses the three specific problems you listed in your question. You'll encounter many other differences if you migrate from an old iText version to a new iText version. Many of these differences are explained in the [online tutorials](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books).